# how to completely override python2.6 with python3.6, no root access

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I'm trying to compile a piece of software, on a linux machine, that requires python. There is a preexisting python 2.6 environment, and a python3.6 environment that I compiled. I want to make sure that any software that is trying to call python has no access to python2.6, nor any of its packages.

1) I can't remove or move python2.6, since I don't have permissions to do so.

2) When compiling the software, I have tried setting environmental variables and aliases:

```
export PATH=/path/to/user_software/python_3_6_0/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/user_software/python_3_6_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/user_software/python_3_6_0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
alias python=python3
alias python-config=python3-config
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

However, python2.6 is located in /usr/bin/, so I can't remove it from $PATH.

3) Would using something like conda handle this automatically?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I should note that when I say "any" software, I mean one executable I call, and any other commands that should call in turn. I don't desire to override python for **all** users, just for myself, for the current session. When running that executable, my idea was to perform the same changes to environmental variables as quoted above.

Comment: Keep in mind that, even if this is possible to do, it may be very inadvisable - a lot of software is specifically made to work with python2, and preventing it from doing so will cause it to crash because of inconsistencies between python2 and python3.

Comment: Keeping in mind what @GCG said above, you might be able to manipulate your user’s $PATH to have **your** programs run 3.6.  But consider that a way to replace one executable with another for **everyone else, without being root**, would be a massive fail in terms of security.  In other words, with a properly secured system at most you should affect your user only and what you are asking for should not be possible.

Comment: Use `virtualenv`? - https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/